# how to get this weekend date in swift?

Tags: ios, swift

If current date is 3 August 2018 (friday), i want to get 4 & 5 august 2018 (saturday and sunday)

if current date is 4 august (saturday), I still want to get 4 & 5 august 2018 (saturday and sunday)

if current date is 6 august (monday) then I want to get 11 & 12 August (saturday and sunday)

how to do that in swift?

Comment: What Timezone is today? perhaps that is your issue. If today is UTC it might actually be your tomorrow, which is Saturday and give you next Saturday August 11

Comment: I just marked your question down, at least before you had code you attempted, you altered your answer to ask simply how to do it without any attempt of your own

Comment: Try this? https://stackoverflow.com/questions/38631176/how-can-i-find-the-next-weekend-swift

Comment: @BrianOgden I am sorry, but I don't wanna limit the answers from other just based on the code from the thread I shared before

Comment: @MartijnPeters Actually that's not a duplicate.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

`Calendar` has convenience methods for that

- `dateIntervalOfWeekend(containing:start:interval:)` checks if the given date is in a weekend and returns the `startDate` and `interval`(duration in seconds) in the inout parameters. The `Bool` return value is `true` if the given date is within a weekend.
- `nextWeekend(startingAfter:start:interval:)` returns `startDate` und `interval` in the inout parameters for the upcoming (`.forward` parameter) or passed (`.backward`) weekend.

---

```
let now = Date()
var startDate = Date()
var interval : TimeInterval = 0.0
if !Calendar.current.dateIntervalOfWeekend(containing: now, start: &startDate, interval: &interval) {
    Calendar.current.nextWeekend(startingAfter: now, start: &startDate, interval: &interval, direction: .forward)
}
print(startDate, startDate.addingTimeInterval(interval))
```

If you need start of Saturday and start of Sunday then replace the last line with

```
let endDate = startDate.addingTimeInterval(interval-1)
print(startDate, Calendar.current.startOfDay(for: endDate))
```

---

Alternatively – suggested by Martin R (thanks) – use `dateIntervalOfWeekend(containing:)` / `nextWeekend(startingAfter:)` which both return a [`DateInterval`](https://developer.apple.com/documentation/foundation/dateinterval) object containing `start`, `end` and `duration`

```
let now = Date()
let calendar = Calendar.current
let weekEndInterval = calendar.dateIntervalOfWeekend(containing: now) ?? calendar.nextWeekend(startingAfter: now)!
let startDate = weekEndInterval.start
let endDate = startDate.addingTimeInterval(weekEndInterval.duration-1)
print(startDate, calendar.startOfDay(for: endDate))
```

Comment: Alternatively: `let weekEnd = cal.dateIntervalOfWeekend(containing: now) ?? cal.nextWeekend(startingAfter: now)!` – the latter would fail only if there are no weekends in the current calendar/locale.

Answer (score 1):

```
let (nextSaturday,orderTotal) = getWeekends()
print(nextSaturday)
print(nextSunday)

func getWeekends() -> (Date,Date) {
        let today = Date()
        let calendar = Calendar.current

        let todayWeekday = calendar.component(.weekday, from: today)

        let addWeekdays = 7 - todayWeekday
        var components = DateComponents()
        components.weekday = addWeekdays

        let nextSaturday = calendar.date(byAdding: components, to: today)
        components.weekday = addWeekdays + 1
        let nextSunday = calendar.date(byAdding: components, to: today)

        return (nextSaturday,nextSunday)
    }
```